# orderBy not working in HTML divs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I am trying to implement a ng-repeat functionality into the divs. For that I need to sort the data first (according to the rank it has, provided from an object) and then name it into the div. So I am creating a **custom OrderBy function** . My sorting functionality works well. However, I am always getting the order of the divs as the same. (Infact, exactly opposite of what I need). I tried using reverse functionalities, but it doesn't work.

My sorting code looks like this:

```
var res = {        
        "Toyota": 2,
        "Ford": 1,
        "Chrysler": 4,
        "Hyundai": 3,
        "Nissan": 5
};

sortedVal = Object.keys(res).sort(function (a, b){
    return res[a] - res[b];
});
```

My HTML div looks like this,

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="name in data | orderBy: sortedVal ">
```

I get the correct output in the console. However, the divs are always arranged in the order given below, no matter what I do.

Nissan, Chrysler, Hyundai, Toyota, Ford.

I need them in the order: Ford, Toyota, Hyundai, Chrysler, Nissan.

**Note: Don't worry about the "name in data" part, it works well. I am having problems with "OrderBy".**

Comment: sortedVal is not a function. It's the result of the call to Object.keys(res).sort(...): the sorted array of keys

Comment: How do I pass it through **orderBy** in this case?

Answer (score 1):

`orderBy` either takes a string for an object property or a function which defines the order. So their is no need to calculate the `sortedVal` yourself, you just need to give `orderBy` the method used to calculate the `sortedVal`:

```
$scope.orderFn = function(a, b) {
  return res[a] - res[b]
}

<div ng-repeat="name in data | orderBy: orderFn"></div>
```

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/lOeblx28wjAV4RCVRxwq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `sortedVal` to the controller scope and then it will be available in the view.

```
var res = {        
        "Toyota": 2,
        "Ford": 1,
        "Chrysler": 4,
        "Hyundai": 3,
        "Nissan": 5
};

$scope.sortedVal = Object.keys(res).sort(function (a, b){
    return res[a] - res[b];
});
```

Or you can create a custom filter to order the objects by value. Something like this.

**Html**

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | orderObjectByValue">
      {{key}} {{value}}
</div>
```

**Js**

```
app.filter('orderObjectByValue', function() {
  return function(items) {
    var filtered = Object.keys(items).sort(function (a, b){
        return items[a] - items[b];
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

**Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/jdIf9hjiUrR6la02aVjA?p=preview

Comment: **sortedVal** gives me the correct order. **orderBy** is not giving me the desired result. In my case, I need to use both orderBy and ng-repeat because I am getting data from two different sources, one for data and one for rank.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS orderBy filter does just support arrays - no objects. So you have to write an own small filter. Please go through the following fiddle it helps you

[http://jsfiddle.net/4tkj8/1/](http://Fiddle)

Comment: I think **orderBy** is working. It is just giving me the incorrect result. Well, it might be working because of something else which I don't know of?